# i want to passs javascript variable in site_url in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

Sir Actually i want previous month details onselect both year and month from two seperate drop down lists.so if select both month and year,previous month balance should display in the below text box;so i just want to pass these two javascript variables through site_url.

```
        $(document).ready(function() {

         $('#mm').change(function(){

          var mm=$(this).val();//get the month
          var yy=$('#yy').val();//get the year
      if($(this).val())
  {
      window.location="<?php echo site_url('controller/function/'...i want to pass var mm and var yy here;?>"


  }

         });
        });



      </script>
<tr><td>Month:</td><td>

    <select name="mm" id="mm" style="margin-left:6px;" >
                               <option value="January">January</option>
                               <option value="February">February</option>
                                  <option value="March">March</option>
                                  <option value="April">April</option>
                                  <option value="May">May</option>
                                  <option value="June">June</option>
                                     <option value="July">July</option>
                                        <option value="August">August</option>
                                           <option value="September">September</option>
                                               <option value="November">November</option>
                                               <option value="December">December</option></select></td></tr>

                             <tr><td>Year:</td><td><select name="yy" id="yy" style="margin-left:7px;    margin-top: 26px;">
                                <?php    
         for($i=1990;$i<3000;$i++)
         {
           echo "<option>".$i."<option>" ;
         }
         ?>




                                </select></td></tr>
```

Comment: If you really expect help, you should invest a few minutes to provide an easy readable minimal example and not just ... something ugly

Comment: sir how will i take month and year in controller

Comment: sir how will i take month and year in controller... function(){ $month=$this->input->post('mm'); but i did not get the value;

Comment: See the answer ... the values are in `$_GET["year"]` and `$_GET["month"]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What  you are trying to do is mixing server and client sided execution. You have to pass month and year as a parameter and handle it in your controller function. This means something like this in JavaScript:

```
window.location = "controller/function/?month=" + mm + "&year=" + yy;
```

And something like this in php / your controller:

```
<?php
  echo 'Year: ' . htmlspecialchars($_GET["year"]);
  echo 'Month: ' . htmlspecialchars($_GET["month"]);
?>
```